# Facebook Debugger Error: "You must preload this data. TAAL[BLAME_file]"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

**When debugging a website with a Like button here:** 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arcosjapan.com%2Fscroll%2Fcaresox-hc.html

It throws a critical error:

> "You must preload this data. TAAL[BLAME_file]".

I have installed hundreds of like buttons and have never run across this. Does anybody know what it means? I am aware of the other issue that it is pointing out on that page: "The app ID specified within the "`fb:app_id`" meta tag is not allowed on this domain." and I am pretty sure that is not the issue as my app is correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Debugger is broken every once in a while. Now it seems to be working again. It gave the same error message just a couple of days ago.